# How to make this horizontal frame to vertical frame that they are align to each other?

Tags: html, css

I made this horizontal frame, now I want to make them into vertical frame.
They should be align to each other and the blue will be on the left and red will be on the right. What should I need to add in the code to make it? Thanks in advance!

```css
#left{
    height:200px;
    overflow:scroll;
    background-color:blue;
}
#allYourContent{
    height:2000px;   
}
#right{
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="left" class="blue">
        <div id="allYourContent" class= "content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="red">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float` to the first div, and (optionally, depending on your content) specify a width.  You can have it float to the left or the right, but `float` must be applied to the first div in the html.  The div that follows will appear beside it and fill the remaining available width.

```css
#left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
#allYourContent {
    height: 2000px;   
}
#right {
    height: 200px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="left" class="blue">
        <div id="allYourContent" class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

```css
    /************/

    .row-fluid {
        display: flex;
    }

   .row-fluid div {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

    /************/

    #left{
        height:200px;
        overflow:scroll;
        background-color:blue;
    }
    #allYourContent{
        height:2000px;   
    }
    #right{
        height:200px;
        background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="left" class="blue">
            <div id="allYourContent" class= "content">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="red">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: flexbox is great, and long overdue, but is a new standard and thus [requires a modern browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility). (IE11+. IE10 supports an older, incompatible version of the standard. IE9 and IE8 have no support)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to give it widths in percentage or fixed values and float the elements in css see below:

```css
/*Left Frame */
#left {width:300px; float:left;}
/*Right Frame */
#left {width:500px; float:left;}
```